# weak convergence in probability theory

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, weak-convergence

I am looking for a book/chapter, where convergence of probability measures (or $\sigma$- finite measures) is analysed through the methods of functional analysis and topology.

Specifically, that $C_K$, $C_0$ and $C_f$ are viewed as topological vector spaces and probability measures as elements of the dual space. So that results about limits are some kind of compactness.

Comment: A canonical reference is *Convergence of probability measures* by Patrick Billingsley.

Comment: This book doesn't mention dual spaces or weak-*-convergence at all. I am especially interested, which consequence the Banach-Alaoglu theorem for probability theory has. Any other suggestions? Did, thank you for your reply though!

Comment: "Topics in weak convergence of probability measures" by Milan Merkle is what i needed.

Comment: I'd add that the books on optimal transport by Villani contain nice chapters on measure theory and weak convergence of probabilty measures (quantified by transport norms).